# Why I got incompatible types?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, incompatibility

```
private Pacman pacman;

public Location whereIsGhost(){
return pacman.getLocation();
}
```

incompatible types: java.awt.Point cannot be converted to ch.aplu.jgamegrid.Location

How to fix it? Which type a compatible with java.awt.Point?

Comment: Why isn't `pacman.getLocation()` returning a `Location` if you have your own `Location` class?

Comment: you could get the values of pacman.getLocation() and then return a new Point with those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have three choices

1. Modify `Pacmage` `getLocation` to return a `ch.aplu.jgamegrid.Location`, or
2. Modify `whereIsGhost` to return a `java.awt.Point`, or
3. Modify `Location` to extend `Point`.

As for which types are compatible with [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) the Javadoc lists no known sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a `Point` object or your `Location` object should extend `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

`Point` does not extends `Location`, therefore it cannot be cast to one.

Simply create a new `Location` based on the parameters of the `Point`.

Both types has no relation to each other.